# The value of a custom dependency property from a derived control doesn't display on property editor window of VS

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I am working on a derived control, a `ToolTip` in my case, and I am facing an issue with its custom dependency properties. Every time I change the value of a custom dependency property to any other than default value, after I run my app and close it, into the Property Editor of Visual Studio the field is empty.

This is a code example of my derived `ToolTip` control:

```
namespace MyControlLibrary.Controls
{
    public class MyToolTip : ToolTip
    {
        public enum IconTypes
        {
            Custom,
            Error,
            Information,
            None,
            Question,
            Warning,
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconType),
                                        typeof(IconTypes),
                                        typeof(MyToolTip),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IconTypes.None,
                                                                      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIconTypeChanged)));

        [Category("MyCategory")]
        [Description("...")]
        public IconTypes IconType
        {
            get { return (IconTypes)GetValue(IconTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnIconTypeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        static MyToolTip()
        {
            //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToolTip), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyToolTip)));
        }

        public MyToolTip()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am testing it into `MainWindow`:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:MyControlLibrary.Controls;assembly=MyControlLibrary"
        
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Button
            Content="MyToolTip Test"
            Cursor="Hand"
            Padding="9"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <MyControls:MyToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="MyToolTip Test!!!"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MyControls:MyToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Before start and close the app:

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 05/05/2023:**

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11wWPAx3d6-uUhnR5Lbye6Sa70G2peA9M/view?usp=share_link) you can download a VS solution which reproduces the issue.

---

**UPDATE 06/05/2023:**

This issue happens when derived control is nested within a `ToolTip`!!!

I created a different derived control, a `TextBlock` for example, with a custom dependency property,  I put it into `<Button.ToolTip>...</Button.ToolTip>` and I have the same issue. But if I put it out of `<Button.ToolTip>...</Button.ToolTip>`, issue ceases to exist!

Looks like something is wrong with the serialization of custom dependency properties values, because when `ToolTip` displayed, a new `Popup` control is created to host the contents of the `ToolTip` and this `Popup` control is not part of the visual tree of the `MainWindow` and therefore any bindings or property values set on the controls inside the `ToolTip` may not be properly serialized. Or something like that.